# CRL distribution point with multiple names

Tags: openssl, crl

I'd like to create a certificate with CRL discribution point, which contains multiple URLs (poiting to the same CRL, according to RFC 5280):

When OpenSSL parses such certificate, it shows something like this:

```
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://addr1
                  URI:http://addr2
                  ...
```

How to create such certificate by myself, preferrably using openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a SEQUENCE of GeneralNames you need to define the crlDistributionPoints in your OpenSSL configuration using the full format:

```
crlDistributionPoints = cdp1

...

[cdp1]
fullname = URI:http://example.com/myca.crl,URI:http://example.org/my.crl
```

Which shows up as:

```
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

            Full Name:
              URI:http://example.com/myca.crl
              URI:http://example.org/my.crl
```

A full example would start by creating a config file (e.g. `example.cnf`):

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
countryName = gb
organizationName = Example
commonName = Example Web Server

[ext]

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = cdp1
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[cdp1]
fullname = URI:http://example.com/myca.crl, URI:http://example.org/my.crl

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.org
```

Use the config to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR):

```
 openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout example.key  -nodes -config example.cnf -out example.csr
```

Note that the above creates a 2048-bit RSA key with no password protection.  Remove the `-nodes` if you need to password protect the private key.

Have a CA sign the CSR generated above.

Comment: that's exactly why I'm asking. I read this manpage, but it shows how to create multiple full names. I need one full name with multiple URLs, as shown in my example